# Writing Jasmine tests for components with ng-content

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm currently learning Jasmine for the purposes of writing tests for Angular2/4 components. There's plenty of documentation on the subject, but info on testing transclusion is surprisingly limited. Is there a way to do this? I'm expecting something like:

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FloatingChatIconComponent, '<div class="content">Here's some ng-content for ya</div>');
```

Is this a thing? Or should I be going about it a completely different way?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you consider using Protractor?

Comment: I'm aware of protractor but I haven't tried using it yet. I'd ideally like to keep all my unit tests written in the same way. does protractor work along side jasmine? is this just impossible to do using jasmine?

Comment: By default, Protractor uses the Jasmine test framework for its testing interface. So I'd say it's possible using Jasmine for your purpose but I can't tell you how since I always use protractor for Angular Testing.

Comment: thanks, i'll look in to that

Comment: How do you want to test ng-content?

Comment: Many different ways. For example, say I have a dropdown component that uses ng-content to allow me to put different elements in the dropdown. I'd like to be able to test to make sure that the data is displayed properly, and that the events on the elements still work properly. Something I've been thinking about is creating a mock test component that implements the dropdown? that probably makes the most sense, right?